# Finding if current page is list or doc-lib page in sharepoint with javascript

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I want to add a javascriptcode  which could run on  to all doc-libs and lists pages.  (NEwForm.aspx,DispForm.aspx,AllItems.aspx and also created custom views)

These lists have common masterpage with the rest of site pages. So i can't place my codes in masterpage.

So is there a way to do it in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking for the library BaseType

- Custom List [0]
- Document Library [1]
- Not used [2]
- Obsolete. Use 0 for discussion boards. [3]
- Surveys [4]
- Issues List  [5]

SPBaseType Enumeration, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasetype.aspx